# Google Api V3 - Adjust strictBounds with zoom

Tags: google-maps, limit

Im trying to build a custom interactive map using Google Maps API. I've gotten as far as creating the custom map tiles and added custom markers with pop up info box. However due to the markers repeating I wanted to limit the boundaries of the map. I have had some success using the strictbounds...

```
  var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
 new google.maps.LatLng(-10, -10), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10)
   );

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() 
   {
 if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

 // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

 var c = map.getCenter(),
     x = c.lng(),
     y = c.lat(),
     maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
     maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
     minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
     minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

 if (x < minX) x = minX;
 if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
 if (y < minY) y = minY;
 if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
   });
```

The Issue im getting however is that it works how I want at the default level 2, but when i zoom through to level 5 the values remain the same limiting panning at that level. I want to be able to pan at the lower zoom levels to the LatLong boundaries of level 5. Is there any way to do this? for instance have the code increase/decrease these boundaries when the zoom level changes?

Hope that all makes sense,

Thank you.

Comment: Or stopping the repeat of markers would also solve the problem. However after looking around this doesn't seem as simple as it sounds...

Comment: I see that it happens even on google maps.... is my only option then to add a lot of whitespace around the image?